# Too many connections to MongoDB Atlas from serverless API (Next.js)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, serverless, vercel

With only about 50 concurrent users on my website, I'm hitting my connection limit (500) on MongoDB Atlas.

My website is build with Next.js and hosted by Vercel. So using serverless functions. I use Mongoose as well.

Seems like every time a request is made to one of my API endpoints - which connects to the database - then a new connection is made to MongoDB Atlas.

I'm using the recommended dbConnect.js file from Nextjs: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/lib/dbConnect.js

And my API endpoints also looks like Next.js suggests:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/pages/api/pets/index.js

What would you guys recommend doing here?

- Upgrade to a dedicated Atlas tier?
- Make a "real back-end" with Heroku (or similar) instead of using Vercel serverless?
- Or preferably, are there some easier option by changing some settings or something? Can I perhaps create one connection per user and maintain it for the users entire visit on the website?

Comment: Thanks for raising this question. This has always been a pain in the a**. I hope we get some interesting suggestions. Also these recommendations doesn't seem to cover scenarios where connection exist but stale.

Comment: I've been facing the issue too, initially things were working fine, also it works locally. But when I deploy it on Vercel, it shows around 30 or 40 connections per page refresh. I am so worried as I raised same question and no one is replying

Comment: @AgentK Hmm I think you might have a slightly different problem then. I haven't observed unusual spikes in connections like you describe.

Comment: @Julius Thanks for your time, but I believe we have same issues because just how you're having 50 concurrent users reaching 500 connections, the same is happening with me, 1 user is having 30/40 connections. Though the situation is different, but I think same solution will work. So can you please help?